# Unsolicited email used email hash from data dump

Tags: discussion, data-dump, privacy

Today, I received an unsolicited email (albeit one that isn't selling a commercial product) from a researcher, who is a user on Stack Overflow. From the unsolicited email itself:

> Using data from GitHub and Stack Overflow, we identified you as a
>   potential participant for our software developer survey. Filling out the
>   questionnaire takes about 10 to 15 minutes. This is a purely academic
>   research project with no commercial interests. We plan to publish the
>   results in a research paper, but we will anonymize all personal data
>   provided by you.

The person who sent this email also tweeted the following on 25 August 2015:

> Does anyone have the Users.xml from the March 2013 @StackExchange data
>   dump? Need it for my research, last dump with attribute EmailHash.

Are data dumps from old months containing email hashes still being made available by Stack Overflow? If so, can they be edited to remove EmailHash? I understand that they can't really do anything about other people storing dumps online, but making it more difficult would be good.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> Are data dumps from old months containing email hashes still being made available by Stack Overflow?

No, none of those are. We don't even have the old XML files anywhere.

We originally partnered with clearbits, who hosted torrents of our data, until they stopped operations. At this point all old torrents were effectively gone (as clearbits were no longer seeders).

Of course, if anyone has downloaded those and made them available (still seeding them, starting a new torrent, via ftp/http, avian carrier etc...), there isn't much we, Stack Overflow, can do about it.

The current data dumps do not have the hash - none of the data dumps ever hosted on archive.org have had it.